# Get values of markers in boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Is there a way to get the values of q1, q3, upper fence, and the outlier data points in a Plotly box plot? I'd like to use these points for additional analysis.

OR, would I be better off using a Pandas function of some sort to get the corresponding data? If so, any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: StackOverflow is not an open-ended, general programming forum, providing *any tips* or recommending software that includes language libraries. We answer specific issues on earnest attempts. Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), give it a try, set up a [mcve], and edit your post with any issues (i.e., errors or undesired results).

Comment: [matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html) returns a dict of [artists](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/artists.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-intermediate-artists-py) (`Line2D` I think). You can get the data from them.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I look into it further, if I use pandas to `describe()` the series that I'm looking at, it provides all the information I need to calculate what I need.

An understanding of interquartile ranges and definition of fences is available [here](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/upper-and-lower-fences/) as well. That page provides instructions on how to calculate.